# How to print bulk document from SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, browser-compatibility, printing

How can we print bulk documents from SharePoint site through the browser? We have to print the documents through browser means at client side not at server side. The printer is not in the server network. User will select multiple projects (that carries various documents) and click on print button. We have to silently print all the documents in client's printer.

Answer (score 4):

An out of the box approach is to open the document library in Windows Explorer (Actions -> Open with Windows Explorer) select the desired files and right click on them.  Then select the print option from the right click menu.

Answer (score 0):

Print Multiple Documents from SharePoint
Simply click on the venerable 'Open with Explorer' option;
In explorer, you can select up to fifteen documents at once, and a print button remains visible. This cuts down the work of multi-document printing a lot!

Regards,
Peter